# Whereto should I migrate my dasBlog site?

Tags: blog, migration, permalinks

For a couple of years I've been hosting [my blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) on my own server. However, I'm getting tired of maintaining it myself, and I also wish to move away from the [dasBlog](http://dasblog.info/) engine, since development of that engine has stopped.

For those reasons, I'd like to move the blog to a service that I don't host myself. It doesn't have to be free.

However, I'd like to **move all the content** of the old blog so that **permalinks will still work** (redirecting to a new URL is also perfectly acceptable). The same goes for the RSS feed and comments.

I was looking at [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com), which looks good, but before I jump into that wanted to ask whether there are other options I should consider?

Answer (score 2):

An other option would be to get a webspace package. Then you don't need to care about the server, you only have to care about your blog. And updating wordpress is very easy and doesn't need much time.

I think you also should consider that if you move your blog to a bloghoster you normally won't have the same control about your blog as you had when it was on your own surfer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what a *webspace package* is?

Comment: I dont't know how to explain it, but you can find hosting packages here for example: http://www.strato-hosting.co.uk/hosting/advanced/

Comment: Obviously that's always a possibility, but I'd prefer not even to have to maintain the blog software any longer... I'm also looking for more concrete suggestions. Still: thanks for your answer (+1).

Comment: I found a list of 40+ blog hosts with different blog platforms: 40+ Free Blog Hosts -> http://mashable.com/2007/08/06/free-blog-hosts/ Maybe this will help you a bit :)

Comment: The main challenge isn't in finding a host. The main challenge is to migrate all the existing content.

Answer (score 1):

[FunnelWeb](http://www.funnelweblog.com/) [**2.1**](https://bitbucket.org/FunnelWeb/release/downloads) was just released, might be an option.

> FunnelWeb is an open source blog engine, built by developers for developers. Instead of fancy quotes and oodles of widgets, we focus on letting you post beautiful code samples, keeping your markup clean and valid, and encouraging collaboration with rich comments. FunnelWeb is easy to install, and has an active community.

For hosting, I'm looking at [Applied Innovations](http://www.appliedi.net/) and [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/asp_net_web_hosting), but I'm open to other ASP.NET MVC providers suggestions.

Comment: How the migration story?

Comment: Since FunnelWeb is MVC based, some routing rules should do it.